# Is it bad practice to add directives dynamically at runtime?

Tags: angularjs, optimization, angularjs-directive

is it bad practice to add directives dynamically to dom nodes at runtime?

like if I had in my controller:

```
if(...){ // some logic if I really want my directive here
  $(element).attr("myDirectiveAsAttribute", "someVal");
}
```

the problem is, that my directive would get added to several dom nodes via ng-repeat (around 20 per page) and I want to keep it performant so i don't need to check in my link function if the directive is needed or not, but only really link the directive when needed.

Comment: It's bad practise to do anything jqLite related to the dom in your controllers

Comment: ok then let's say the decision takes place in another directive

Comment: How do you mean performant? Are those 20 watches on your page not performing? If so maybe you need to take a close look at your directive that you are inserting then and take a look at the number of watches on your page.

Comment: That approach won't work. If you add an attribute directive to an element, you need to use the `$compile` service to invoke and link the directive to scope. The `ng-if` directive does that for you if you want to make the decision in another directive but beware, `ng-if` adds a child scope.

Comment: thanks for the hint regarding $compile. what about a solution like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ftfish/KyEr3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is ng-attr-my-directive

one can use it like this when the directive would be "my-directive":

```
<div ng-attr-my-directive="myVal == 'myCondition'"></div>
```